# Integrating unity with android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I was trying to build an app using two platforms unity and android studio. While I am building the app, following error occurred.

Could not find :unityandroidpermissions:.
Required by:
project :app > project :unityLibrary

How to resolve this?

I tried changing the Onclick function in mediator file, export the file again, adding dependencies and so on. Nothing was successful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.